# How to scrape highlighted table data in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape only selected highlited rows in selenium from a database

I only want blue, purple and yellow coloured rows

[image]

of 2356 rows

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
 
from selenium import webdriver
  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 


driver = webdriver.Chrome() 

driver.get ("https://www.fieo.org/Offrings-from-Indian-Exporters.php")

que=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contant-contant']/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[3]/b/a")

que.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example with one of them.

```
#,[@bgcolor='#C6C600'],[@bgcolor='#70B8B8']
elements=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@bgcolor='#C184FF']")))
#print(len(elements))
for elem in elements:
    print(elem.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Outputs

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="49516">3F INDUSTRIES LIMITED&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>[TH]</strong></td>
                                    <td>TURMERIC</td>
```

... And so forth. If you want only the text use elem.text.

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```